# The first validation error encountered was "Apex trigger CannotDelete caused an unexpected exception

Tags: apex, trigger, class

This is my trigger code

```
 trigger CannotDelete on Account (before Delete) {

 sample_class sample = new sample_class();
 sample.CannotDelete(trigger.old);


}
```

This is my apex class

```
 public class sample_class{

public void CannotDelete(List<Account> angelacode) {
    for (Account a : [
            select Id, (select Id from Contacts)
            from Account
            where Id in :angelacode
            ]) {
        if (a.Contacts.size() > 0) {
            a.addError('CannotDelete');
        }
    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your actual error is (helps when you open the dev console and look at the logs):

> SObject row does not allow errors

Debug log:

> 09:52:07.131 (131544163)|EXCEPTION_THROWN|[6]|System.FinalException:
>   SObject row does not allow errors 09:52:07.131
>   (131817605)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[6]|Bytes:37 09:52:07.131
>   (131872744)|METHOD_EXIT|[4]|01p61000005V4qu|sample_class.CannotDelete(List)
>   09:52:07.131 (131942551)|FATAL_ERROR|System.FinalException: SObject
>   row does not allow errors
>
> Class.sample_class.CannotDelete: line 6, column 1
>   Trigger.CannotDelete: line 4, column 1 09:52:07.131
>   (131958867)|FATAL_ERROR|System.FinalException: SObject row does not
>   allow errors
>
> Class.sample_class.CannotDelete: line 6, column 1
>   Trigger.CannotDelete: line 4, column 1

Since you are doing this for a trigger you need to pass ing the map and add the error there.

**Class**

```
public class sample_class{

    public void CannotDelete(Map<ID,Account> angelacode) {
        for (Account a : [select Id, (select Id from Contacts) from Account where Id in :angelacode.keySet()]) {
            if (a.Contacts.size() > 0) {
                angelacode.get(a.id).addError('CannotDelete');
            }
        }
     }
}
```

the pass in `trigger.oldmap` instead of `trigger.old`

Also take sfdxfox's code for the loop (in his answer) and use it

Comment: thank you @Eric, I am new in coding and I want to understand further the code. How does Map<ID,Account> works and what is the angelacode.keyset() handles?

Comment: @gelay - Map collection documentation here - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_collections_maps.htm

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to add an error to the queried value, not to the records from Trigger.old/Trigger.oldMap. To fix this, you can use a simple aggregate result query:

```
public void CannotDelete(Map<Id, Account> accounts) {
    for(AggregateResult result: [SELECT AccountId Id FROM Contact WHERE AccountId IN :accounts.keySet() GROUP BY AccountId]) {
        accounts.get((Id)result.get('Id')).addError('You cannot delete accounts with contacts.');
    }
}
```

And, instead, pass Trigger.oldMap instead of Trigger.old to this function.