# oldMap in Apex Class

Tags: apex, trigger, class

I am new in apex coding and I dont understand map very well, I just want to understand what this code means.. Thank you in advance, please bear with me.

```
 public class sample_class{

   public void CannotDelete(Map<ID,Account> angelacode) {
     for (Account a : [select Id, (select Id from Contacts) from Account where Id in :angelacode.keySet()]) {
        if (a.Contacts.size() > 0) {
            angelacode.get(a.id).addError('CannotDelete');
        }
    }
 }
}
```

What does Map means? how does it work?
What does the .keyset() handles?
what does for (Account a : [select Id, (select Id from Contacts) from Account where Id in :angelacode.keySet()]) means because I was confused with the (select Id from Contacts)

thank you

Comment: gelay, it sounds as though you'd greatly benefit from going through the [Trailhead Modules](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/modules) on Apex code and on Triggers. All these kinds of things are covered as are many of the questions you've been asking here over the past several days.

Comment: I suggest you go with sfdcfox's answer to your question [The first validation error encountered was "Apex trigger CannotDelete caused an unexpected exception](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/97902/the-first-validation-error-encountered-was-apex-trigger-cannotdelete-caused-an) because it is more efficient and more elagant - the query returns only the ID values of the Accounts you want to set the error on.

Answer (score 0):

Hi There are 3 kind of collections available in APEX.
1.List (ordered and allow duplicates)
2.Set (unordered and won't allow duplicates)
3.Map (Key and value pair)
 Map holds key and value pair.
//Syntax: Map mapName = new Map();

/*Map countryISTCodeMap = new Map();

countryISTCodeMap.put('India','91');
countryISTCodeMap.put('USA','001');
countryISTCodeMap.put('India','911');

//replaces old value with new value.*/
Map countryISTCodeMap = new Map{'India'=>'91','USA'=>'001', 'India'=>'911'};

system.debug('countryISTCodeMap result: '+countryISTCodeMap+' with size '+countryISTCodeMap.size());
system.debug('countryISTCodeMap keys: '+countryISTCodeMap.keyset());
system.debug('countryISTCodeMap values: '+countryISTCodeMap.values());
system.debug('countryISTCodeMap search: '+countryISTCodeMap.containsKey('India'));
system.debug('countryISTCodeMap fetching value based on key: '+countryISTCodeMap.get('India'));
//map keys are case-sensitive.

Below are the MAP methods:

1.keyset(): To fetch only keys from the map.
2.values(): To fetch only values from the map.
3.containsKey(value): To search a key from the map.
4.get(key): By supplying the key we can fetch the value.
5.put(key,value): To add key and value in a map.

Hope this will help you.
Plz let me know if you need further help.

Russell

Comment: In the code above,  Map(Id, Account) it pertains that example the Id is 001 and the account is 'ME'. it would be like this? Map sampleMap = new Map{'001'=>'ME'};